# Recycleview custom layout constraint are changing for each inflated view causing problems

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

I have a recyclerview that inflates data fetched from json.

The issue I am facing are design issues - sometimes the text is aligned correctly and the image is shown and sometimes the text is too long, causing what I think is for the image not to be shown.

here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="395dp"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:background="#335634"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/heroImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/heroTitle"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="25dp"
            android:autoSizeMinTextSize="15dp"
            android:text="Hero Title"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/heroDescription"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:breakStrategy="simple"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="36dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="25dp"
            android:autoSizeMinTextSize="15dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/heroImage"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/heroTitle" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

and here is my adapter:

```
public class HeroesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HeroesAdapter.HeroesViewHolder> {

    private List<Hero> heroList;

    public HeroesAdapter(List<Hero> heroList) {
        this.heroList = heroList;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public HeroesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View rowView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.hero_cell, parent, false);
        return new HeroesViewHolder(rowView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull HeroesViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Hero currentHero = heroList.get(position);
        String str = String.join(",", currentHero.abilities);

        holder.heroTitle.setText(currentHero.title);
        holder.heroAbilties.setText(str);
        Picasso.get().load(currentHero.image).resize(500,500).into(holder.heroesImage);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return heroList.size();
    }

    public static class HeroesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView heroesImage;
        TextView heroTitle;
        TextView heroAbilties;


        public HeroesViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            heroesImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.heroImage);
            heroTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.heroTitle);
            heroAbilties = itemView.findViewById(R.id.heroDescription);
        }
    }
}
```

[This is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzrcF.jpg) the result I am getting and [this is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jv52z.jpg) the wanted result.

the issues I am facing are:

1. making each row have a clean design and act the same for all.
2. images are sometimes shown, sometimes not.
3. bottom view is "half in screen" and half out of screen.

Comment: Why a ConstraintLayout inside another ConstraintLayout? The ConstraintLayout must be 375dp or should math the parent width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your expectation, you should use card-view and I've updated the layout. Please check

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    android:elevation="10dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="395dp"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:background="#fff"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/heroImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/heroTitle"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="25dp"
            android:autoSizeMinTextSize="15dp"
            android:text="Hero Title"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/heroDescription"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/heroImage"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/heroDescription"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="25dp"
            android:autoSizeMinTextSize="15dp"
            android:breakStrategy="simple"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="#444"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/heroImage"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/heroTitle" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: now I am left only with one issue to fix - some of the images do appear and others don't, but the other that don't appear leave a blank space - causing me to suspect about it being something layout-related and not code related. am I correct?

Comment: Then you can add a default image so that the user can understand that there is no image for that item.

Comment: add a check in your adapter if there is an image or not.
if(currentHero.image!=null && currentHero.image!="")
 Picasso.get().load(currentHero.image).resize(500,500).into(holder.heroesImage);

Comment: You can also set width and height for image-view

Comment: I found something about the ending of the url. it seems like piccaso can't handle .png endings and won't show them - do you know anything about that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194035/discussion-between-alon-shlider-and-koushik-mondal).

Comment: I've not faced any issue with Picasso with png image URL. For example, see this.   
Picasso.get()
                .load("https:// futurestud.io/images/books/picasso.png")
                .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                .error(R.drawable.error)
                .into(binding.picassoImage);

Comment: Please use the latest version of this library. see this
 https://github.com/square/picasso

Answer (score 2):

By using LinearLayout you can design your hero_cell that will give you the desirable output. as I do it for now.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="#335634"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/heroImage"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:background="#335634"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/heroTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="25dp"
            android:autoSizeMinTextSize="15dp"
            android:text="Hero Title"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/heroDescription"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:breakStrategy="simple"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="25dp"
            android:autoSizeMinTextSize="15dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="18dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
```